# Truobles with Windows Update Domain Policy on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, windows-update

I got a problem with Windows Update Domain Policy.

The Domain Policy is configured with automatic automatic download of updates, but dont installation (Option 3). Everytime i check the policy and state of windows update it's functioning well, but sometimes the state of windows update on the server changes to Automatic Updates and i don't know why. When i use `gpupdate/force` the policy aplyes correctly again.

I checked every part of the policy and i wasnt's able to locate the problem.

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching a solution for this trouble, i found an option that may help.

```
I changed the policy refresh interval setting as follows:

 - Group Policy Refresh Interval for Domain Controllers: Enabled with 5 minutes intervals.
 - Registry Policy Processing: Enabled with "Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed" option.
```

To change these settings edit the Default Domain Controllers Group Policy object and go to:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy
```

Here is where i readed everything to do that:

[Group Policy Processng](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758898%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)